# Increasing CSS Keyframe Speed Gradually

Tags: css, frontend, css-animations, web-frontend, keyframe

I have found this HTML/CSS that will create a rotating text title that I have previously made using JS and encountered problems. Using this @keyframe script, how would I increase the rotation speed? So it starts really slow and builds up to faster, holds the faster pace for a period of time and then reduces back to the slower pace?

CSS

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins",sans-serif;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

body {
  background-color: #0e6ffc;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.words {
  overflow: hidden;
}

span{
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #0e6ffc;
  animation: spin_words 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes spin_words {
  10% {
    transform: translateY(-112%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  35% {
    transform: translateY(-212%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-312%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(-300%);
  }
  85% {
    transform: translateY(-412%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-400%);
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be good if you include your HTML code.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set timing for your animation. see this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

For your code, it will be something like this:

```css
/* I assumed the element you're animating has #box id. Of course you can use any other seelctor */
#box { 
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: not useful for a) looping animations and b) animations that dynamically change statre (i.e. making it play faster on hover)